# Unhandled exception within my menu

Tags: c++, class, exception, getline

I am currently getting a unhandled exception in my code and I have no idea why. This is the first time I am using more than one class together.

At the moment I am trying to put user input into a string from another class. I am trying to input the user input into a string called name in the class below

```
#ifndef SHIP_H
#define SHIP_H
#include "ApplicationMenu.h"
#include <string>
class Ship
{
public:
    Ship(void);
    ~Ship(void);

    std::string _size;
    std::string _shipName;
    std::string name;
};

#endif
```

Into the following function which is ran in main

```
#include "ApplicationMenu.h"
#include "Ship.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

class Ship;

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

ApplicationMenu::ApplicationMenu(void) { userChoice = 0; }


ApplicationMenu::~ApplicationMenu(void) { }



void ApplicationMenu::displayMenu() {


    cout << "Welcome to the Port." << endl << "Please select one of the
        following options : " << endl
        << "1: Dock Ship" << endl;
    cin >> userChoice;
    switch (userChoice)
    {
    case 1:

        Ship*   ship;

        ship->name;


        cout << "Please enter the name of your ship your wish to dock: ";
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        getline(cin, ship->name);

        cout << ship->name;
        break;
    }
}
```

Can anyone please advise why I am getting error?

Edit:

This error was because of an uninitialised pointer which was due to the lack of knowledge about pointers in C++. Although this was answered by the community this link would prove helpful for future viewers. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Comment: You should inspect such situations by using the debugger and stepping through your code line by line. What should be the purpose of this code line `ship->name;` BTW?

Comment: It is a string I am trying to read user input into.

Comment: Yes, we can see that. But what should this line do actually? And don't distract from my main advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an uninitialized pointer `Ship* ship;`.  You either need to use `Ship*  ship = new Ship();` or declare the ship as `Ship ship;`

Comment: that definitely seems like the problem, but I'm not entire how he is even hitting that code anyway.  `userChoice` isn't updated anywhere outside the constructor, and should always be 0

Comment: @dwcanillas I am using the assumption that he updated `userChoice` in code he hasn't shown here since the code posted wont even compile as is so it is not a complete example.

Comment: Sorry I missed this out I get the userChoice from `cin >> userChoice;`

Comment: Thank you this fixed it. I am just learning pointers so it is new to me.

Answer (score 1):

Ship* ship is an unitialized pointer that points to a random memory location which you then try to access. You should always initialize pointers to **nullptr** or to a valid object to prevent undefined behavior.

```
Ship* s( new Ship );
```